# How do I center this HTML button

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering my HTML button.

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/j1rpupgx/

Html:

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td style="border-radius: 0px; background-color: #f66511; display:   block;" width="138" height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#2251a4"><a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15px; font-family: sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 30px; width: 100%; display: inline-block;" href="https://www.onvia.com/">Get Started</a></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: add margin in your table <table style="margin: 0 auto;">

Comment: That's not a button, its a cell in a table. You'd have to either put a blank cell on each side of it, not recommended. Or put a margin, also not recommended. Use the button tag, recommended.

Comment: Creative code indentation you have got going there

Comment: First thing to do is remove that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific example you can simply add the following CSS:

`table{margin:0 auto;}`

Here is a full working snippet:

```css
table{margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-radius: 0px; background-color: #f66511; display: block;" width="138" height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#2251a4"><a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15px; font-family: sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 30px; width: 100%; display: inline-block;" href="https://www.onvia.com/">Get Started</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Or, just add `style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"` to the `<table>`.

Comment: Well, he may have other tables on the page that he doesn't want centered... A middle ground would be to add some `class` to the table, and use that in the CSS selector.

Comment: True, he could have the entire universe in his code.  But without further detail or insight into the rest of the code, for his specific question, this answers it with the least amount of code possible.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #f66511;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;         
    width: 138px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <a class="btn" href="https://www.onvia.com/">Get Started</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<center>`before opening div and end it after ending div, like this:

```
   <center>
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-radius: 0px; background-color: #f66511; display: block;" width="138" height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#2251a4"><a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15px; font-family: sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 30px; width: 100%; display: inline-block;" href="https://www.onvia.com/">Get Started</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
       </div>
  </center>
```

I've also made a JSFiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/k1krs98z